# Email template not showing the background image in hotmail

Tags: css, magento, templates, html-table, html-email

I just created a newsletter template in magento for one of my customer.
but the issue is it isn't showing the background header image in Hotmail Gmail Yahoo etc.
It is showing perfectly fine in test environment and in webmail but not in any Outlook etc.
Here is the code for you all.
Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Newsletter</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top"><table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td height="90" align="center" valign="top" style="background-image:url(http:placehold.it/350x150.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center top;"><table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td width="300" height="90" align="left" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.mysite.co.uk"><img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/logo.png" width="177" height="48" alt=""/></a></td>
                  <td width="300" height="90" align="right" valign="middle"><img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/contact-us.png" width="146" height="47" alt=""/></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="35" align="left" valign="top" style="background-image:url(http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/menu_bg.jpg); background-repeat:repeat-x; background-position:center top;">
            <a href="https://www.smartteck.co.uk" style="line-height:35px; padding:0px 8px; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:arial; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase;">Home</a>
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.ukpc-components.html" style="line-height:35px; padding:0px 8px; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:arial; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase;">PC COMPONENTS</a>
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.ukdesktop-pc-s.html" style="line-height:35px; padding:0px 8px; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:arial; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase;">DESKTOP PC’S</a>
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.uklaptops.html" style="line-height:35px; padding:0px 8px; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:arial; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase;">LAPTOPS</a>
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.ukmonitor-tv-s.html" style="line-height:35px; padding:0px 8px; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:arial; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase;">MONITOR & TV’S</a>
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.ukstorage.html" style="line-height:35px; padding:0px 8px; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:arial; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase;">STORAGE</a>
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.ukgaming-gadgets.html" style="line-height:35px; padding:0px 8px; color:#FF0000; font-family:arial; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase;">SALE</a>

            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           {{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}
<td align="center" valign="top"><table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="email-heading">
                        <h1>Thank you for your order from {{var store.getFrontendName()}}.</h1>
                        <p>Once your package ships we will send an email with a link to track your order. Your order summary is below. Thank you again for your business.</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="store-info">
                        <h4>Order Questions?</h4>
                        <p>
                            {{depend store_phone}}
                            <b>Call Us:</b>
                            <a href="tel:{{var phone}}">{{var store_phone}}</a><br>
                            {{/depend}}
                            {{depend store_hours}}
                            <span class="no-link">{{var store_hours}}</span><br>
                            {{/depend}}
                            {{depend store_email}}
                            <b>Email:</b> <a href="mailto:{{var store_email}}">{{var store_email}}</a>
                            {{/depend}}
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="order-details">
            <h3>Your order <span class="no-link">#{{var order.increment_id}}</span></h3>
            <p>Placed on {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="order-information">
        <td>
            {{if order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="message-container">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/if}}
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h6>Bill to:</h6>
                        <p><span class="no-link">{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}</span></p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h6>Ship to:</h6>
                        <p><span class="no-link">{{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}</span></p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h6>Shipping method:</h6>
                        <p>{{var order.shipping_description}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h6>Payment method:</h6>
                        {{var payment_html}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<tr>
            <td height="20" align="center" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="56" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#dcdcdc">
            <img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/brand-1.jpg" width="110" height="35" alt=""/>
            <img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/brand-2.jpg" width="110" height="35" alt=""/>
            <img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/brand-3.jpg" width="110" height="35" alt=""/>
            <img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/brand-4.jpg" width="110" height="35" alt=""/>
            <img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/brand-5.jpg" width="110" height="35" alt=""/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="75" align="center" valign="middle">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/SmartTeckLtd"><img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/facebook.jpg" width="31" height="31" alt=""/></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="https://twitter.com/SmartTeck_Ltd"><img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/twitter.jpg" width="31" height="31" alt=""/></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/+SmartteckUk/"><img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/gplus.jpg" width="31" height="31" alt=""/></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.uk#"><img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/pinterest.jpg" width="31" height="31" alt=""/></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.uk#"><img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/youtube.jpg" width="31" height="31" alt=""/></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.uk#"><img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/instagram.jpg" width="31" height="31" alt=""/></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.uk#"><img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/linkedin.jpg" width="31" height="31" alt=""/></a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="33" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#1696da" style="color:#FFFFFF; font-family:arial; font-size:12px;">&copy; Copyrights 2016 Smart Tech 786 Ltd, Registered Number 09713584.</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="20" align="center" valign="top" style="line-height:40px; font-size:11px; font-family:arial;">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: these are the trouble making line

Answer (score 0):

Email with html can be ... difficult, so use the old markup way

```
<td height="90" align="center" background="myback.gif">...</td>
```

Side note

You have a typo as well, which will fix the issue for email clients supporting newer css styles, where you forgot the 2 forward slashed in your url, so change  `http:placehold...` to `http://placehold...`

```
style="background-image:url(http://placehold.it/350x150); ..."
```

---

If you still have issues with inline style, you might want to change the header background, where you remove it from the td and add it to the table, like this

```
          <td height="90" align="center" valign="top">                
            <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" background="http://placehold.it/350x150">
```

Comment: hi,i used this way as well but it messes with whole of template. this is part creating trouble "td height="90" align="center" valign="top" style="background-image:url(http:placehold.it/350x150.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center top;"><table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tbody>

Comment: @shafiq Here is also an old how-to tutorial: http://www.htmliseasy.com/table_tutor/background.html

Comment: Hi Thanks but this isnt the issue, these i missed when replacing the customers website links. any thing else you noticed?

Comment: @shafiq Yes, remove the `.jpg` as well from the url, so it looks like this `http://placehold.it/350x150`

Comment: @shafiq I also found stray tags so you need to clean up the markup a little

Comment: original image is a .jpg format so i can not remove this. which stray tags you noticed? please point those to me.

Comment: @shafiq You can't use `.jpg` on that _placehold.it_ link, it will not work. Line 47 and line 149 has stray close tags (a `tr` and a `tbody`) ... also made an update of my answer that might help

Comment: hi mate, it isnt worked. i so confused tried your edit in answer as well but it does not show the image in full. will have to start from scratch. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try including a full url in the css

like this for example: 
https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150&fm=jpg

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Newsletter</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="top"><table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td height="90" align="center" valign="top" style="background-image:url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150&fm=jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center top;"><table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td width="300" height="90" align="left" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.mysite.co.uk"><img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/logo.png" width="177" height="48" alt=""/></a></td>
                  <td width="300" height="90" align="right" valign="middle"><img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/contact-us.png" width="146" height="47" alt=""/></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="35" align="left" valign="top" style="background-image:url(http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/menu_bg.jpg); background-repeat:repeat-x; background-position:center top;">
            <a href="https://www.smartteck.co.uk" style="line-height:35px; padding:0px 8px; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:arial; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase;">Home</a>
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.ukpc-components.html" style="line-height:35px; padding:0px 8px; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:arial; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase;">PC COMPONENTS</a>
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.ukdesktop-pc-s.html" style="line-height:35px; padding:0px 8px; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:arial; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase;">DESKTOP PC’S</a>
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.uklaptops.html" style="line-height:35px; padding:0px 8px; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:arial; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase;">LAPTOPS</a>
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.ukmonitor-tv-s.html" style="line-height:35px; padding:0px 8px; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:arial; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase;">MONITOR & TV’S</a>
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.ukstorage.html" style="line-height:35px; padding:0px 8px; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:arial; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase;">STORAGE</a>
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.ukgaming-gadgets.html" style="line-height:35px; padding:0px 8px; color:#FF0000; font-family:arial; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; text-transform:uppercase;">SALE</a>
            
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           {{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}
<td align="center" valign="top"><table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="email-heading">
                        <h1>Thank you for your order from {{var store.getFrontendName()}}.</h1>
                        <p>Once your package ships we will send an email with a link to track your order. Your order summary is below. Thank you again for your business.</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="store-info">
                        <h4>Order Questions?</h4>
                        <p>
                            {{depend store_phone}}
                            <b>Call Us:</b>
                            <a href="tel:{{var phone}}">{{var store_phone}}</a><br>
                            {{/depend}}
                            {{depend store_hours}}
                            <span class="no-link">{{var store_hours}}</span><br>
                            {{/depend}}
                            {{depend store_email}}
                            <b>Email:</b> <a href="mailto:{{var store_email}}">{{var store_email}}</a>
                            {{/depend}}
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="order-details">
            <h3>Your order <span class="no-link">#{{var order.increment_id}}</span></h3>
            <p>Placed on {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="order-information">
        <td>
            {{if order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="message-container">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/if}}
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h6>Bill to:</h6>
                        <p><span class="no-link">{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}</span></p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h6>Ship to:</h6>
                        <p><span class="no-link">{{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}</span></p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h6>Shipping method:</h6>
                        <p>{{var order.shipping_description}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h6>Payment method:</h6>
                        {{var payment_html}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<tr>
            <td height="20" align="center" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="56" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#dcdcdc">
            <img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/brand-1.jpg" width="110" height="35" alt=""/>
            <img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/brand-2.jpg" width="110" height="35" alt=""/>
            <img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/brand-3.jpg" width="110" height="35" alt=""/>
            <img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/brand-4.jpg" width="110" height="35" alt=""/>
            <img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/brand-5.jpg" width="110" height="35" alt=""/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="75" align="center" valign="middle">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/SmartTeckLtd"><img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/facebook.jpg" width="31" height="31" alt=""/></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="https://twitter.com/SmartTeck_Ltd"><img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/twitter.jpg" width="31" height="31" alt=""/></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/+SmartteckUk/"><img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/gplus.jpg" width="31" height="31" alt=""/></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.uk#"><img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/pinterest.jpg" width="31" height="31" alt=""/></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.uk#"><img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/youtube.jpg" width="31" height="31" alt=""/></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.uk#"><img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/instagram.jpg" width="31" height="31" alt=""/></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="http://www.mysite.co.uk#"><img src="http://www.mysite.co.uknewsletter/linkedin.jpg" width="31" height="31" alt=""/></a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="33" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#1696da" style="color:#FFFFFF; font-family:arial; font-size:12px;">&copy; Copyrights 2016 Smart Tech 786 Ltd, Registered Number 09713584.</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="20" align="center" valign="top" style="line-height:40px; font-size:11px; font-family:arial;">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```